# How do I calculate the total number of seconds of inputed hours, minutes, and seconds in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

any ideas on how to do this? I'm stuck...

I came up with...

```
 >>> def print_seconds(hours, minutes, seconds):
...     print(int(hours) * 3600)
...     print(int(minutes) * 60)
...     print(int(seconds) * 1)
... 
>>> print_seconds(1,2,3)
3600
120
3
```

but how do I sum this up together?

Comment: Something like `print(int(hours) * 3600 + int(minutes) * 60 + int(seconds))`?

Comment: Also, there's no need to call `int(...)` on values that are already integers.

Comment: Yep. Thanks! I feel dumb now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
def print_seconds(hours, minutes, seconds):
        hours = (int(hours) * 3600)
        minutes = (int(minutes) * 60)
        seconds = (int(seconds) * 1)
        totalTime = hours + minutes + seconds
        print(totalTime)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def print_seconds(hours, minutes, seconds):
    a = int(hours) * 3600
    b = int(minutes) * 60
    c = int(seconds) * 1
    print(int(hours) * 3600)
    print(int(minutes) * 60)
    print(int(seconds) * 1)
    print(a+b+c)

print_seconds(1,2,3)
```

Output

```
3600
120
3
3723
```

You don't need to create the variable. You can straight declare the existing formula. I just show it, so that you can easily visualize it.

Answer (score 0):

```
def print_seconds(hours,minutes,seconds):
    return (int(hours)*3600)+(int(minutes)*60)+(int(seconds))
```